# What is the term for special words that don't use standard readings or regular modifications?

Tags: terminology

Words like 大人、下手、上手... as おとな, へた, じょうず.
What is the name for terms of this type?

Not including: 
[Kanji that don't use their specified readings](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38728/kanji-that-dont-use-their-specified-readings).
The answers for おみやげ don't answer the classification of non-standard pronunciation (they answer other questions but the stated one).
The おとな related question is very specific to that word.
I believe the other stated duplicate doesn't answer this in general either. 
It would very hard for a searcher to find these somewhat duplicate questions.

Comment: Note that [上手 and 下手 each have several readings](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3092/78), some of which *are* standard.

Comment: With regard to your most recent edit... those other questions mention 熟字訓. That is the answer to the question in your title.