# Pronunciation of 上下

Tags: pronunciation, readings

上下 has lots of potential pronunciations:

1. じょうげ
2. うえした
3. しょうか
4. かみしも

Are there any guidelines on how to know which readings to use? I'm particularly interested in this sentence:

> 顔が**上下**に割れるかと思ったほど大きくにっこりして、...
>   *The person* grinned so hard that he thought his face might split from top to bottom.

But I'd also be interested in more general thoughts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As for your example, both じょうげ and うえした will work and I don't think I can choose one.

The first reading [じょうげ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/108085/meaning/m0u/%E4%B8%8A%E4%B8%8B/) is the most versatile one that spans across a number of related meanings as well as grammar:

1. *n.* top and bottom, upper and lower, the former and the latter (volumes), inbound and outbound (traffic); (*adverbially*) above and below
2. *n.* all from top to bottom, high and low
3. *n.* the quality of up and down, verticality, height, tallness, hierarchy, rank; (*adjectively*) vertical, hierarchical
4. *v.* move up and down, fluctuate, bounce; *n.* fluctuation, bouncing

[うえした](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/17554/meaning/m0u/%E4%B8%8A%E4%B8%8B/) and [かみしも](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/44835/meaning/m0u/%E4%B8%8A%E4%B8%8B/) each shares a small portion of the definition #1 (and #3) shown above. You can refer to [Ups and downs: かみ・しも vs うえ・した](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3090/7810) for their difference, but simply put, うえした is used for something really "vertical", and かみしも specially for those customarily assigned "up" and "down" and not very "vertical".

- うえした: for physical position, dimension, direction and hierarchy
- かみしも: for river (up- and downstream), stage ("upper" (=left) and "lower" (=right)), kimono (top and bottom pieces), [tanka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanka) etc.

But うえした has one unique sense not in じょうげ: "upside down" by its own (= 上下（じょうげ・うえした）逆). The similar usage can also be seen in native words 前後ろ, 裏表, 右左 etc.

しょうか is... never used anymore, except that since it is all-漢音 reading, it must (prescriptively) be used instead of じょうげ whenever [we read Classical Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanbun). For other meanings kindly [consult the dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/107560/meaning/m0u/%E4%B8%8A%E4%B8%8B/), because they are foreign to us too :)

> [故【ゆえ】に上下【しょうか】能【よ】く相【あい】親【した】しむなり。](https://kanbun.info/keibu/kokyo17.html)
>   *Hence, as the superior and inferior, they are able to have an affection for each other.* ([James Legge](https://ctext.org/xiao-jing/service-of-the-ruler))